# asp:listbox, don't autopostback until clicked outside

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, listbox, autopostback

this might seem like kind of a weird request, but I'm looking to prevent autopostback for selected index change until the user clicks outside of the listbox, instead of when the user selects/deselects an item.

Is such a thing possible?  The reason I ask is I have the [following plug in](https://github.com/HemantNegi/jquery.sumoselect) used for a multiselect dropdown.

As it is right now, autopostback closes the dropdown each time a user select an item, and the index is successfully changed.  However, if I turn autopostback off, it stays open to allow the user to select multiple items, but it won't register as selected.

If anyone could suggest a means of doing this I would be eternally grateful.  Thanks so much in advance.

I'll post my asp.net and c# codebehind for the multiselect below.

ASP.NET

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:ListBox ID="DependenciesListBox" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="300px" CssClass="search-box-sel-all" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Select Child Dependencies" ToolTip="Items that depend on this currency item" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DependenciesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

C#

```
protected void DependenciesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ChildLabel.Text = "";
    foreach (ListItem item in DependenciesListBox.Items) {
        if (item.Selected)
            ChildLabel.Text += item.ToString() + ", ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not add a client event and postback based on your required condition using javascript. If not satisfied, return false/cancel postback.

Comment: I am absolutely brutal at javascript.  I'm a student on my first co op and haven't been taught/shown javascript/jquery except briefly in a client/server class.  An example would be absolutely awesome.

Comment: Alright, added some more content as an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
   <asp:ListBox ID="DependenciesListBox" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="300px" CssClass="search-box-sel-all" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Select Child Dependencies" ToolTip="Items that depend on this currency item" AutoPostBack="False" onchange="clientListChanged(this);" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DependenciesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>


//Java script code
     function clientListChanged(el)
     {
      if ( el.value == '1' ) // for all indexes you dont want to post back add condition
      { 
       return false;
      } 
      return true; //else postback
     }
```

Use `onblur` event for the event when user clicks outside the box and do a post back. I'm not sure if it allows html markup with list box; if not add via code behind using `attributes.add` for the list box. Then you can probably use __doPostBack(elementName.ClientId) in asp quotes to post to server

*Note: I have not tested the code for errors or syntax issues. I just wrote it down here in editor. So please fix any errors you find.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know perfect answer,

But this works for me, i hope it will work for you

Use updatepanel triggers

```
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger
ControlID="DependenciesListBox"
EventName="SelectedIndexChanged
="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
```